# Disable a button from different ViewController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

So I want to enable/disable a button from that tableViewCell :

```
class CommonPromoCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var optionBtnCommon: UIButton
```

when another buttons are enable/disabled from other tableViewCell

```
 class PromoButtonCell: UITableViewCell {
 @IBOutlet weak var option1Btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var option2Btn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var option3Btn: UIButton!
```

So mainly I want when one from option1 to option 3 are selected to make the `optionBtnCommon` enabled, and when none from the above 3 buttons are selected to disable it.

I've tried something like

```
var viewController: PromoButtonCell?

// TODO : DISABLE COMMON BUTTON WHEN NO OTHER IS SELECTED
        if (viewController?.option1Btn.isSelected)! || (viewController?.option2Btn.isSelected)! || (viewController?.option3Btn.isSelected)! {
            optionBtnCommon.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            optionBtnCommon.isEnabled = false
        }
```

the if written in the `func` of the `#selector` of `self.optionBtnCommon.addTarget`

EDITED :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentPackage = self.packages[indexPath.section]
    switch indexPath.row {

    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PromoButtonCell") as! PromoButtonCell
        cell.populate(currentPackage)
        cell.contentView.tag = (indexPath.section + 1) * 10
        return cell

    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommonPromoCell") as! CommonPromoCell
        cell.populate(currentPackage, forPayment: self.payments[self.paymentIndex].type)
        cell.optionBtnCommon.tag = indexPath.section
        return cell
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you save the instance of `var viewController: PromoButtonCell?` and how?

Comment: I've declared it in  `CommonPromoCell: UITableViewCell` . Forgot to mention that it crashes when force unwraps it

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel Please show me your TableView. and you can not do anything like this as you stated in above comment.

Comment: What exactly from my mainTableVIew?

Comment: @dahiya_boy i've edited my question if that's what are u lookin' for

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel Show me that vc screen. I wanted to know hows its UI. Just run your project and goto that screen and capture it and show me. It will be more helpful for me to answer.

Comment: https://ibb.co/n7SKpm    |||||||||       
           https://ibb.co/d6ZcaR ||||||||||||
            https://ibb.co/cE5Th6 ||||||||||||
            https://ibb.co/nnPcaR   ||||||||||||
             https://ibb.co/e8NxaR

Comment: As you can see in the last link i dont wannt that button to be selecteed from the second row

Answer (score 0):

If the user can change the state of option1Btn and option2Btn you will need to implement some kind of event handling between the `PromoButtonCell` and the view controller, to modify the state of `CommonPromoCell`.

I would create a protocol, so that the `PromoButtonCell` can inform your viewController that the cell state changed. Lets say you create  `PromoButtonCellDelegate` with events like `promoButtonCell:UITableViewCell didSelectButton: UIButton`.

Then the viewController can implement that protocol, and when receiving the event, try to access the other `CommonPromoCell`, to change its state.

How does it sound like?

Comment: Hello so I've created in the `PromoButtonCell`  viewcontroller `protocol PromoButtonCellDelegate: class {
    var promoButtonCell: UITableViewCell? {get}
    var didSelectButton: UIButton? {get}
}`  with `weak var commonDelegate: PromoButtonCellDelegate?`  and in the `CommonPromoCell`  I've created the extension `extension CommonPromoCell: PromoButtonCellDelegate {
    var promoButtonCell: UITableViewCell? {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    var didSelectButton: UIButton? {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    
}`   Is it good? Thanks